# How to duplicate manyToOne in doctrine yaml using the same Entity

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, yaml

i want to get the users and employees from the same Entity and use them in the same Entity also.

```
manyToOne:
  User:
    targetEntity: \UserBundle\Entity\User
    joinColumn:
      name: user_id
      referencedColumnName: id


manyToOne:
  User:
    targetEntity: \UserBundle\Entity\User
    joinColumn:
      name: employee_id
      referencedColumnName: id
```

when i use the first part it works perfect and the second one don't seems to be working.  After i updated the schema still no employees.

What do you think guys should i do?

so it is also not working!

```
manyToOne:
  User:
    targetEntity: \UserBundle\Entity\User
    joinColumn:
      name: user_id
      referencedColumnName: id
    joinColumn:
      name: employee_id
      referencedColumnName: id
```

Comment: What you present is an invalid YAML file. It is not allowed to have the same key twice in one mapping, and you have `manyToOne` twiced in the toplevel mapping. You should read the YAML documentation focussing on http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#mapping//

Comment: That's right thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering Doctrine documentation :
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

`manyToOne:
  user:
    targetEntity: \UserBundle\Entity\User
    joinColumn:
      name: user_id
      referencedColumnName: id
  employee:
    targetEntity: \UserBundle\Entity\User
    joinColumn:
      name: employee_id
      referencedColumnName: id`